# Remove the integrals of equivalent expressions

Tags: integration

If we have two mathematical expressions $E$ and $F$ that are equals, then we can integrate both sides: $E=F$ $\Rightarrow$ $\int E=\int F$

Can we have the equivalence in the other sense, i.e.: $\int E=\int F$ $\Rightarrow$ $E=F$? Why?

Comment: if you mean for definite integral, then the result does not hold. Consider the integral of $x$ from -1 to 1 , which is 0 and the integral of 0 from -1 to 1 which is also 0!

Comment: I meant the indefinite integral.

Comment: You just edited this 8 year old question, which puts it on the active question queue. Do still really need the answer?

Comment: @EthanBolker: Yes, I do.

Answer (score 2):

The indefinite integral of a function $E$ is a set of functions - the functions with derivative $E$. If the indefinite integral of $E$ is the same set as the indefinite integral of $F$ then the derivative of any function in that set is both $E$ and $F$ so they are equal.

Comment: In other words, does $\int E=\int F$ $\Rightarrow$ $E=F$ stand?

Comment: Yes. But the assertion is strange in that form. I can't see a context in which I would find it useful. I suggest you think carefully before invoking it formally. Do remember that a function has many indefinite integrals.